# NoteSession cannot find Notes.ini on server

Tags: .net, session, lotus-notes

I have a vb.net that interacts with Lotus Notes; however, I have a problem when I make a NotesSession. Every time I try to make a notesSession, I get an error because it can't find the notes.ini.

If I put the notes.ini file in C:\Program Files\lotus\notes my app will work, but I can't have it there I need it to be on my companies server w:\Lotus\Notes.

I can't seem to find a way to make it search elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, all the bad stories I heard about Notes must be true.  Try setting Environment.CurrentDirectory to the directory that contains that .ini file

Comment: Quite sad, yet I am quite happy! I needed to find a solution quite fast :p thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You might also just need to add the w:\Lotus\Notes dir to your environment path

Comment: yup, that works too, i forgot to mention though, that i am not allowed to change the environment path. But thanks for the help :)